# Cannot execute command line using php

Tags: php, linux, blast

I tried to run command line for local BLAST. I already download the package and allow the permission for every files and folders. But still I can't display the output of it at my page.

```
echo shell_exec("/opt/lampp/htdocs/blasto/bin/blastp -query /opt/lampp/htdocs/blasto/result/INF2dWxh -db /opt/lampp/htdocs/blasto/db/*.faa -evalue 10 ");
```

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

`shell_exec` will only return STDOUT.  Any error messages written to STDERR will be lost unless you add `2>&1` to the end of your command.  This will redirect anything written to STDERR (file descriptor #2) to STDOUT (file descriptor #1) which will be returned by `shell_exec` and displayed by `echo`.  So, try this ...

```
echo shell_exec("/opt/lampp/htdocs/blasto/bin/blastp"
    . " -query /opt/lampp/htdocs/blasto/result/INF2dWxh"
    . " -db /opt/lampp/htdocs/blasto/db/*.faa"
    . " -evalue 10"
    . " 2>&1"
);
```

Comment: I try that and come out with this   ---> /opt/lampp/htdocs/blasto/bin/blastp: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)

Comment: Great news!  You now have the error message describing why it failed.  You're much better off now than when you had nothing.

Comment: thanks for your help. Somehow I managed to get the output after find libgcc_s.so.1 file.